# Extract text and nodes from mixed content and in the document order in xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

I need to extract the text and node values from mixed content node. I can extract either nodes or text but not both. How do I do it in xpath. Please help. Thanks for your time. Here's an example:

```
let $xml :=  <param name="expr" type="xs:string">
      The XPath expression string to evaluate. The XPath expression must be
      of the form returned by <code xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">xdmp:path</code>.
      some othe test goes here
      <pre>some code here</pre>
      and some more text content here
     </param>

     return $xml
```

I can get text by `$xml/text()` and nodes by `$xml/*`. But I need both and listed in the same order as it appears

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `node()` to get both *text nodes* and *element nodes* :

```
$xml/node()
```

Comment: You're awesome! Thanks mate!

Comment: while we're here, how do I stringify node. 
Ex: "<pre>some code</pre>"